# Injecting 360 video metadata with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, xml, metadata

I'm working on a library that injects/embeds/writes metadata into a .mp4 file to allow the video to be displayed correctly as a 360 video. The input file is a standard .mp4 file in the equirectangular format which I need to inject the proper metadata to get it to display as a 360 video. I know tools like Google's [Spatial Media Tool](https://github.com/google/spatial-media) exist but if possible I would like to do it with ffmpeg.

This is what I have tried already but it does not work:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -movflags use_metadata_tags -metadata Spherical=true -metadata Stitched=true -metadata ProjectionType=equirectangular -metadata StitchingSoftware=StreetviewJourney -codec copy output.mp4
```

I have tried many variations of it like adding `GSpherical:` and `xmp:` to the metadata tag.

The metadata injected by the Spatial Media tool looks like this and is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><rdf:SphericalVideo
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:GSpherical="http://ns.google.com/videos/1.0/spherical/"><GSpherical:Spherical>true</GSpherical:Spherical><GSpherical:Stitched>true</GSpherical:Stitched><GSpherical:StitchingSoftware>Spherical Metadata Tool</GSpherical:StitchingSoftware><GSpherical:ProjectionType>equirectangular</GSpherical:ProjectionType></rdf:SphericalVideo>
```

### Edit 1

When I extract the metadata using ffmpeg it contains the spherical tag in the logs but not when I output it to a ffmetadata file. This was the command I used: `ffmpeg -i injected.mp4 -map_metadata -1 -f ffmetadata data.txt`

This is the output of the log:

```
 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Side data:
      spherical: equirectangular (0.000000/0.000000/0.000000)
```

### Edit 2

I also tried to get the metadata using this command: `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_streams -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 injected.mp4`

This was the logs it outputted:

```
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
side_data_type=Spherical Mapping
projection=equirectangular
yaw=0
pitch=0
roll=0
```

I then tried to use this command but it didn't work: `ffmpeg -i chapmanspeak.mp4 -movflags use_metadata_tags -metadata side_metadata_type="Spherical Mapping" -metadata projection=equirectangular -metadata yaw=0 -metadata pitch=0 -metadata roll=0 -codec copy output.mp4`

Comment: Could you provide example data?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?   I have 360 video and after I use FFmpeg to convert it from fisheye to equirectangular I'm losing the "always upright" characteristic that is preserved by the native software.  I'd like to know if the data can be preserved during conversion or added later.

Comment: No, I never did figure it out.